# Do files from trusted location have macros enabled by default (without notification)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to understand trusted location vs macro settings.

If macro setting is to not run and show notification, and the file belongs to a trusted location then does the macro setting get overridden and the macro runs without the notification?

Comment: If a file is from a Trusted Location, the macros in the file will be enabled by default without any notification. This means that if the macro setting is to not run and show notification, but the file belongs to a trusted location, then the macro setting will be overridden and the macro will run without the notification.

Answer (score 0):

From
[Add, remove, or change a trusted location in Microsoft Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c6714):

> A trusted location in Microsoft Office is a folder that contains files
> you trust to be safe.
>
> You should use a trusted location to store a file when you don't want
> that file to be checked by the Trust Center, or if you don't want it
> to open in Protected View. **Especially files with macros**, data
> connections, or ActiveX controls (what we call active content).
>
> If you think the active content in a file is from a reliable source,
> the best practice is to move the file to a trusted location.
>
> Caution: Any files you store in a trusted location are considered safe
> by the system and will bypass some of the security checks. Be certain
> that you trust the source of any files you put there.

This means that a macro-containing document from a trusted location
will be opened without a problem.

Comment: Do you mean if file is located in trusted location, then when file is opened will launch without `Enable Content` notification even if the macro setting is: Disable macro with notification?

Comment: I mean that if file is located in trusted location, it will not be checked by the Trust Center of Office. Other settings that are not in Trust Center will still be enforced.

Comment: But the macro setting (disable with notification) is in trust center. So will this apply or not? And what does it exactly mean by `it will not be checked by Trust center`?

Comment: This is what the documentation says, Office won't check, but Windows will.